# What does $x -> {_foo} -> {_bar} in Perl mean?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to understand a Perl script and I dont understand one declaration line which is:

```
$pin =  $x -> {_foo} -> {_bar}
```

whereas **_bar** is an undef variable declared in another sub.

Comment: See [perldoc perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) for more information about the syntax

Comment: `_bar` is almost certainly not a variable. It's just a string.

Answer (score 4):

The value of `$x` is expected to be a reference to a hash.

`$x->{_foo}` is the value of the element with key `_foo` of the hash referenced by `$x`.

That value is expected to be a reference to a hash.

`$x->{_foo}->{_bar}` is the value of the element with key `_bar` of the hash referenced by `$x->{_foo}`.

For example, it would return `123` for the following:

```
my $x = {
   _foo => {
      _bar => 123,
   }
};
```